# How to add a UITableview inside a UIImageview programmatically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to add a UITableview inside a UIImageview programmatically in Swift 3, I have tried it with Xcode default UIImageview and UITableview, but my application got crashed.

Comment: You should add more detail and some code you have tried, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it stands your question makes very little sense

Comment: You can put tableview over imageview, you can not addSubview in imageview.

Comment: what the issue u faced , so your tried code, finally show some UI what type of OP your expect

Comment: my requirement is i want to load a uitableview inside a UIImageview , if it is not possible shall i use uiview instead of UIimageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add a UITableView inside UIImageView. 
You can take a UIView and add UIImageView and UITableView inside this view.

```
let bgView = UIView.init(frame: self.view.frame)   //Frame of the view
    let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: bgView.frame.width, height: bgView.frame.height))   
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imgDefault")
    let tableView = UITableView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: bgView.frame.width, height: bgView.frame.height))
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    bgView.addSubview(imageView)
    bgView.addSubview(tableView)
    self.view.addSubview(bgView)
```